# How do I complain to Stack Exchange about one of its communities?

Tags: conflict-resolution, stack-exchange

I am having a difference of opinion with the users and moderators on a Stack Exchange community.  I claim that the questions I ask are all in accordance with the rules of the site, but because my questions challenge some baseline ideas, they are deleted.  How can I escalate my compalint about this injustice to Stack Exchange authorities?

For example, this is [my question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-it-true-that-in-islam-men-enjoy-more-value-and-privilege-how-god-the-religi).

Comment: Please read the comments. Your question **IS** too broad. And (repeat) *SE is not meant for arguments and discussions with followups, its a Q&A site*. You may not like that, but those are the rules, so trying to escalate this has no use. The site is just not appropriate for what you want, you will have to find another place for these kinds of discussions.

Comment: BTW I'm sort of 'replying' here in a comments (not an answer) because I'm not sure your question is on-topic here, [meta.se] would be better. There are [similar questions there already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+moderator+complaint), and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges) looks like a duplicate of your question here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first place to raise concerns about something that happened on a Stack Exchange site is on that site's associated meta site.  Meta is for questions *about the site*, including:

- How is (this closed question) too broad? What do I need to further specify?
- Is (this topic) really off-topic, or did I just ask it wrong (here)?
- I disagree that (this) is a duplicate of (this); can we reopen?
- Why is (this question) still open?
- (This) was an answer to a product question, not spam!
- How should we handle (controverial-topic) questions?

Etc.

Most decisions that are made on a site are community-owned, so you need to discuss differences of understanding in that community.

You won't always agree with the outcome, of course.  If it's a matter of scope boundaries, Stack Exchange is unlikely to get involved -- they defer to the users of the site, who are presumed to have some relevant expertise and interest.  If you feel that something *else* is going on, like if you think the site isn't following SE-wide policies like Be Nice or you feel that a personal difference with a moderator is having broader effects, then you can use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page on the site to contact the SE Community team.  Use the form to explain your concerns, and be sure to include links to specific posts if relevant.  It usually takes a few days to get a response, so be patient.

Comment: Most communities welcome complaints, especially if they're phrased as opportunities to improve. Barrier to entry is a big thing with Stack Exchange, so if we're scaring people away, especially newer people, we want to know to possibly adapt. That said, while constructive criticism is welcomed, ranting isn't going to get anyone anywhere, so think about what you want to get out of the question. (That should go without saying... but ya know...)